# How do I know if a simple pole exists (and how do I find it) for $f(z)$ without expanding the Laurent series first?

Tags: complex-analysis

In general, how do I recognize that a simple pole exists and find it, given some $\Large f(z)$? I want to do this without finding the Laurent series first.

And specifically, for the following function:

$\Large f(z) = \frac{z^2}{z^4+16}$

Comment: To find poles of rational functions, look for zeros of their denominators. To see if a pole is simple, see if it is a simple root of the denominator.

Comment: So your example has simple poles at each of the four 4th roots of -16.

Comment: I don't understand what a "simple root of the denominator" is. I get that the 4th roots of -16 is a pole. However, I don't understand how it is a simple pole.

Comment: The denominator of a rational function will be a polynomial. A root $r$ of a polynomial $p(x)$ is a simple root if the linear factor $x-r$ only appears once in its complete factorization.

Comment: Without knowing the complete factorization, you can still check which roots, if any, are simple: a root $r$ of $p(x)$ is simple iff it is not a root of $p'(x)$.  So any non-simple roots of $p(x)$ will be roots of $\gcd(p(x),p'(x))$.  If the gcd of $p(x)$ and $p'(x)$ is $1$, all roots are simple.

Comment: In your example, the only root of $(z^4 + 16)' = 4 z^3$ is $0$, which is not a root of $z^4+16$, so all roots of $z^4+16$ are simple.

Answer (score 2):

Addressing Joebevo's first comment to BruinJ's answer:
$$z^2-4i=0\Longrightarrow z=\pm \sqrt{4i}=\pm 2\sqrt i=\pm 2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}i\right)=\pm\sqrt 2(1+i)$$
and now you factor easily:
$$z^2-4i=\left(z-\sqrt 2(1+i)\right)\left(z+\sqrt 2(1+i)\right)$$
You can do simmilarly for the other quadratic factor.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(z) = \frac{z^2}{z^4 + 16} = \frac{z^2}{(z^2-4i)(z^2+4i)} = \frac{z^2}{(z\pm (1+i)\sqrt{2})(iz+ (1+i)\sqrt{2})((1+i)\sqrt{2}-iz)} $$

Even if you couldn't have factored $(z^2-4i)$ or $(z^2+4i)$, you should be able to see it could factor into *unique* terms of order 1. The rest is pretty straightforward from your book.

Edit: sorry I totally factored wrong haha. But you get the point heh.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't quite understand how to get from step 2 to step 3, which is important if I want the exact expression for the pole. How exactly did you factor those terms? Is there a general method?

Comment: it's just the difference of two squares

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you find the roots of $z^4+16=0$,

$$ z^4 = -16 \Rightarrow z^4 = 16\, e^{i\pi} \Rightarrow z^4 = 16\, e^{i\pi+i2k\pi} \Rightarrow z = 2\, e^{\frac{i\pi + i2k\pi}{4} }\, k =0\,,1\,,2\,,3\,.$$